# Which approach should I use for retrieving details from this multi-table SQL instruction?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have 3 tables.

**users**

```
id | user_email | user_password | user_name
```

**communities**

```
id | name | code | admin
```

**community_players**

```
community_id | player_id
```

A user is logged into my app with their email address (`$email`).

I want to use that email address to look up which communities they are apart of.

My logic current logic is:

```
SELECT id FROM table users WHERE user_email = '$email' (call this new variable 'A')

SELECT community_id FROM table community_players WHERE player_id = 'A' (call this new variable 'B')

SELECT name FROM table communities WHERE id = 'B'
```

What approach should I take:

1) Come up with a single MySQL Statement that accomplishes the above in one go and returns an array of community names.

or

2) Run 3 separate MySQL statements each returning a variable in PHP to use in the next SQL statement (like the logic I used above)

or some other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY this in single query using JOIN  [docs mysql Join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html)

```
SELECT communities.name 
FROM users 
join community_players 
on community_players.player_id=users.id 
join communities 
on communities.id=community_players.community_id   
WHERE users.user_email = '$email'
```

Comment: Excellent! That worked a treat! Really glad that has saved me having to do more PHP work!

Comment: glad to help you @RichardDowns